# Fragment Caching in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku

I have been experimenting a lot with caches and memcache server/services in rails and I'm trying to fragment cache some complex views.

The problem is, my current host (heroku) only supports fragment caching if I have an external service providing the cache (ironcache/memcachier). [Heroku's caching guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies)

However having an external service for caching worsen the performance of my app.
My guess is because of many http requests from another server.

I also tried low level cache in heroku and both using memcache services. It's good but I have to speed up my app more.

1. Is there any other way to fragment cache in heroku?
2. Why is it my app is slower when storing the cache in another service?
3. Why is there a need to use an external memcache service to fragment cache in heroku isn't it that the fragment cache is stored in memory_store same with
   low level cache's

Comment: so the performance of your app get's worse when you introduce fragment caching? that does not sound like you are doing it the right way

Comment: no, when I use fragment cache via a mamcache service (ex. via ironcache/memcachier)

Comment: i don't understand your comment. when is it fast, when is it slow?

Comment: when I use a service as a mem_store (storing the cache in ironcache/memcachier) it tends to be slower.

Comment: slower than no cache at all. Is it because of the extra http request?

Comment: why are you caching parts when they are fast to compute? of course, calling an external resource is way more expensive then computation on the same host. caching only makes sense if you can prevent calling more expensive resources, say your database or a rest-service

Comment: According to this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies for fragment cache to work on heroku, you need an external resource. Maybe fragment caching isn't that viable on heroku

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: What I'm saying it, I think the article evcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies is not viable to follow. Because fragment caching from an external resource is slow. AND there's no way to fragment cache in heroku without an external resource.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it using an external memory for caching is a standard way to go for apps that have multiple dynos. Even if the memcache and your app are not physically the same machine you should still get decently fast response depending on the cache memory structure and the amount of data that goes through the network.

There may be some other problems with your setup that makes retrieving cache slower than usual. Maybe try a different service besides ironcache/memcachier?